# Adding new XML records online

Tags: php, xml

I'm putting a scoreboard on my client's website. It's similar to what's at the top of espn.com.

In order to populate it, I have an xml file, that's set up like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scores>
<game>
 <sport>Boys Soccer</sport>
 <awayName>Spartans</awayName><awayScore>2</awayScore>
 <homeName>Kings</homeName><homeScore>1</homeScore>
 <date>Oct 10</date>
</game>
<game>
 <sport>Girls Hockey</sport>
 <awayName>Wildcats</awayName><awayScore>7</awayScore>
 <homeName>Cougars</homeName><homeScore>3</homeScore>
 <date>Oct 02</date>
</game>
</scores>
```

In order for the client to easily update it with new scores (and remove old ones), I would like to create a webpage that they can log in to and edit the xml page. I assume this will be done with php, but I have little idea where to start, especially since newest scores should be added to the top.

Is this worthwhile trying to figure out, or should I just stick to editing the xml file with Notepad and uploading it through FTP?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to be very careful when letting users write to files on your web server.

Comment: It would only be the clients themselves who would be editing the file.

Comment: Even then, the form needs to be protected behind some type of authentication, and the input and output should be verified before writing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a HTML form.
2. Read the XML and populate the form data
3. Have the client (end-user) edit the form.
4. Submit the form to a PHP script
5. Have the PHP script write the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like a Google Docs spreadsheet? You and the client can both have access, and you don't have to write any user interface code for editing the data. Your web page can then query the Google Docs API to get the data. If you want to get fancy, you could cache the data to improve performance and reliability, but I'd guess Google Docs is pretty fast and reliable.

Comment: Thanks, Don. I hadn't considered Google Docs. I might give it a shot.